# Changing the value that lParam points at

Tags: c++, mfc, sendmessage, lparam

I'm using Visual C++ /MFC and I'm sending a message as `SendMessage(GetParent(hDlg) ,MY_MESSAGE , 0 , LPARAM(x) );`

How could I change the value of `x` inside the `hDlg` parent callback function ?

For example if I send the message `SendMessage(hWnd , WM_GETTEXT ,0 , LPARAM(buffer);` the buffer is returned full of the text . How did the buffer changed it's value ?

Comment: You'll need `&x` if you want to change the variable's value.  You don't need `&buffer`, a reference to a C array already automatically decays to a pointer to its first element.

Comment: Alright I know this ,but my question is how to change the value inside the callback .

Comment: Cast the lparam argument back to (whateverxmightbe*) and assign the value.

Answer (score 1):

(buffer) is a pointer to some memory that has already been allocated. The WM_GETTEXT operation can use that pointer to put data into the allocated memory. You can do the same thing if your (x) variable is a pointer to some memory that has already been allocated.

Comment: I need to know how to make the same